# Изменение содержимого с помощью dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Подскажите,пожалуйста,как реализовать вот такую штуку c использованием dropdown: есть выпадающий список с моделями машин,когда выбираешь какую-то модель меняется содержимое слайдера с шинами.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: мдаа.а ваши попытки реализовать подобное конечно нету и вы хотите чтобы вам дали все готовое на блюдечке

Comment: Покажите результат ваш. Это можно по разному реализовать. Можно с базы данных подгружать инфу по шинам. Можно сделать Partial View для каждой из модели которые будут подгружаться при выборе.